# Regex for Currency of any country like INR USD

Tags: java, regex

I want to create the regex for currency of any country for that,I am preparing on regex in java

```
public Static CURRENCY_FORMAT= ^(([-+][1-9]\\d{0,2}(,\\d{3})*)|(([1-9]\\d*)?\\d))(\\.\\d\\d)?$
public static final String GBP = "GBP";
public static final String USD = "USD";

public static final List<String> CURRENCY_LIST=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(GBP,USD));
```

now I want to use this list to add in front of currency with 1 white space
For E.g. "USD 123.23" or "INR 89.78"
I am creating list of currency because if in future I have to add new currency so I can easily do that.
I tried this but its not working.

```
public Static CURRENCY_FORMAT= "^\\["+CURRENCY_LIST+" ]"+^(([-+][1-9]\\d{0,2}(,\\d{3})*)|(([1-9]\\d*)?
```

Comment: yeah,that it true,at the time of editing I misplace that thing...but downgrade question is not worth unnecessary...I dont know who did this,its not good..After searching a lot I came here..I already know the Currency class but want to do that in regex..anyway god bless you

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`java.util.Currency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) ?  Much simpler and you get an instance per `Locale` which you should read from the OS properties, or ask  user for input. It also provides the **symbol**, the **name** and the **number of decimal digits**, which should address most of your needs.

Comment: its not feasible for me,for now I am supporting only 2 currencies type,so dont want to change my whole implementation.

Comment: You should throw your implementation away and use the standard mechanisms instead. Using regular expressions for something like this is just ridiculous.

Comment: thats correct,I am agree with you for time being I have to restrict to regex only..is there any combination by which I can support only INR and USD.I am new to regex so not able to manipulate it.

Comment: @vicky9988 going down the regex route is not great. You mention the need to extend this list in the future - this will create ever spiraling regex impossible to maintain. Just as a quick observation your regex now requires the string to start with `+` or `-` and some decimal places **OR* no sign without any decimal places. What about amounts without a sign (implicit `+`) but with some decimal places ?

Comment: @diginoise,I think you are right...it will take more time to implement but good for future as well..BTW I have that sign,it was removed at the time of editing